# Spring 4 to 5 migrate, error when connecting Oracle db. (ORA-01017)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, migrate, ojdbc

I am trying to migrate Spring from **4.3.14** to **5.0.4** in my Spring application.

Unit tests and integration tests run fine, but when I try to debug the application it gives error:

> 2018-02-19 15:39:51,948 ERROR
>   org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements
>   - Unable to use JDBC Connection to create Statement
>   **org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon
>   denied**

This is not the case with 4.3.14. It works ok. Error occurs if I only change the version number of Spring to 5.0.4 in pom.xml. So, username and password are not the reason.

- ojdbc8 (12.2.0.1)
- hibernate (5.1.0.Final)
- JDK 8

Can anyone help? Do you need more details?

Comment: Have tried enabling the debug traces to see precisely what's going on? I would also suggest to check your database configuration (where the logon credentials are retrieved from). My best guess is that there is some kind of profile or something that messes up you ORA login capabilities.

Comment: The error is pretty explicit - the username/password are invalid. This doesn't mean that the credentials are wrong. It most likely means that they're not being set correctly in your Spring configuration. Maybe post more configuration details about how you are setting those credentials.